# Javascript: Drawing on canvas won't work because of calling a function

Tags: javascript

I currently am working on making mastermind in javascript. I'm now making the visual part. The code I'm working on should draw squares and fill them with a color that you give in. It works ok, untill I define a variable for wich I use an earlier defined function. The drawing, that works when I don't define that variable all of a sudden won't work.

My code for drawing 8 lines of 4 squares is:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="520" style="border: 1px solid #000000;">...</canvas>
```

```
var j = 0;
var scomb = makeSecretComb();
while(j<9){  
var i = 0;
var colors =[];

while(i<4){
  var a = prompt("Give in a color");
  colors.push(a);

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(50*(i), 50*(j+1), 50, 50);
  context.fillStyle = a;
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 7;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
  i = i+1;
}

  j=j+1
 }
```

Without the variable scomb, I can draw the squares, with scomb in the code I get a blank canvas.
Any idea how this may be?

Comment: Can you paste complete script?

Comment: Does it show any errors in the console? My guess is that `makeSecretComb()` throws an exception and the rest of the script is not executed.

Comment: `<script type = "text/javascript">`
  
       ` function getRandomInt(;min, max) {`
   `return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;`
   `}`
     
  `function makeSecretComb(){`
  `var colors = ["green","purple","blue","yellow","orange","black"];`
  `var secretcomb = [];`
  `for (i=0;i<4;i++) {`
  `var j = getRandomInt(0,5);`
  `var y = colors[j];`
  `secretcomb.push(y);`
  }
  `return secretcomb;`
  }` 
`</script>`

Comment: This is my code for makeSecretComb